# Salam. I have recently done self-harm by cutting my thighs. i didn't realize it was haram at the time. Would it still be counted as haram?

Tags: halal-haram, forgiveness, tawba

I was in a really bad place a few months ago. People I know of share their scars to each other and I felt pressured to try it. Once I tried it, I couldn't stop. My mother eventually realized about it and told me it was haram. It's been three weeks since I stopped, and the deeper scars are still very visible.